# Reg Ex to Split and Replace the string javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to split the specific portion's of string and replace it with the new Value.

Example : `var _string = "split and replace @123/0 and test @456/1 and so on..."`

From the above string I need to replace @123/0 with @123.00/0 and @456/0 with @456.00/0.

Final Output : `"split and replace @123.00/0 and test @456.00/1 and so on..."`

I am searching a more generic way because there might be n number of @val/ in a string. I am unable to replace the specific portions of string.

This is what I tried:

```
var _string = "split and replace @123/0 and test @456/1 and so on...";
var regex = /\$[^\@]*\/0/g;
var match = _string.match(regex);

for(var i=0; i<match.length; i++){
  if(match[i].indexOf("@") > 0){
    // do replace of string...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with `replace()` alone using the correct RegEx with group captures. Try this:

```js
var _string = "split and replace @123/0 and test @456/1 and so on...";
_string = _string.replace(/(@\d{3})\/(\d)/g, "$1.00/$2");
console.log(_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method with a callback function.

```js
var _string = "split and replace @123/0 and test @456/1 and so on...";

console.log(
  _string.replace(/@(\d+)\/(\d)\b/g, function(_, m1, m2) {
    return '@' + m1 + '.00/' + m2;
  })
)
```

---

Or you can avoid the callback by providing the [string as parameter option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) in  [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method.

```js
var _string = "split and replace @123/0 and test @456/1 and so on...";

console.log(
  _string.replace(/@(\d+)\/(\d)\b/g, '@$1.00/$2')
)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var _string  = "split and replace @123/0 and test @456/1 and so on...".replace("@123/0", "@123.00/0").replace("@456/1", "@456.00/0");
```

Try this

Comment: Given the OPs mentions this needing to be generic I believe the whole point is that the replacement values cannot be hard-coded